# Inserting specific columns of csv file into mongodb collection using python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, csv, pymongo

I have a python script to insert a csv file into mongodb collection

```
import pymongo
import pandas as pd
import json

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")

df = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")

data = df.to_dict(oreint = "records")

db = client["Database name"]

db.CollectionName.insert_many(data)
```

Here all the columns of csv files are getting inserted into mongo collection. How can I achieve a usecase where I want to insert only specific columns of csv file in the mongo collection .

What changes I can make to existing code.

Lets say I also have database already created in my Mongo. Will this command work even if the database is present (db = client["Database name"])

Comment: In Pandas, it's easy to create a new dataframe while selecting the columns you want from another dataframe ... or drop columns from a dataframe.  Would that satisfy your needs?

Comment: FYI, the `rust` app [`xsv`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv#readme "Link to GitHub repo -->") is awesome at processing, selecting, formatting, etc., CSV files - and it's fast!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out pymongoarrow? the latest release has write support where you can import a csv file into mongodb. Here are the [release notes](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/pymongoarrow-0-4-0-released/160444) and [documentation](https://mongo-arrow.readthedocs.io/en/0.4.0/quickstart.html). You can also use mongoimport to import a csv file, documentation is [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/#general-csv-import), but I can't see any way to exclude fields like the way you can with pymongoarrow.